# How do I run Tomboy in the notification area at startup?

Tags: indicator, startup, tomboy

I tried adding `tomboy` in System -> Preferences -> Startup Applications, but this causes the "Search All Notes" window to appear every time I log in. I just want it to run in the notification area so that I can use it later via hotkeys or its notification area icon popup menu.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an undocumented option `--icon` that makes tomboy start without showing a window. It HAD a bug ([bug #566421](https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/566421)), which has now been resolved.

Also, you can use the **tomboy applet**: Right click on the panel, choose “Add to Panel” and select “Tomboy Notes“. The panel applet looks similar to the notification area icon and provides the same functionality (hotkeys and popup menu).

Comment: Thanks, `tomboy --icon` works for me.

Comment: Does this also work for the numerous notes that will automatically open (I guess because they were open when shutting down)? I'd like to stop tomboy from opening any note when loading.

Comment: tomboy --icon works fine in ubuntu 13.04 using Startup Application Preferences. bug #566421 does not apply, so please remove the reference to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1.

Go to System Tools >> Preferences >> Startup Applications and Click "Add"

Fill in the windows

Name: Tomboy Notes

Command: tomboy --indicator

Comment: Take notes, link ideas, and stay organized

Then click "Add"

### Method 2

Open the dash and start typing Startup Applications.

When it shows up, click on it to open it. Click "Add", then continue from "Fill in the windows" above.

### Method 3.

Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type "gnome-session-properties" to launch the startup Applications manager. Click "Add", then continue from "Fill in the windows" above.

Answer (score 0):

The search menu will appear if the panel is not ready. Use a script like `#!/bin/sh && /bin/sleep 18 && /usr/bin/tomboy` instead of plain tomboy

Answer (score 0):

"I just want it to run in the notification area"
I want Tomboy's search selection yellow "Tomboy Notes" icon to always appear in the bottom panel strip of my Linux Mint 17 Qiana, Cinnamon 2.2.16 program.
Problem I had: Icon would sometimes be on panel and sometimes not, but would always appear after 2 or more hours later. Drove me crazy.
I have this bottom panel strip set to minimum height.

**Solution:** I found that if I increased the height of the panel strip, The icon would appear instantly.