# Tomboy won't start

Tags: 10.10, tomboy

I've just discovered Tomboy and like it. I added it to the startup applications, and on next boot **Tomboy won't start.** It then also won't start when I select it manually from the menu.

- I unchecked its entry in the startup applications and rebooted, but it still won't start.
- I uninstalled it and installed it again in order to perhaps fix some broken file or setting, but it didn't help.
- I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4819/how-do-i-run-tomboy-in-the-notification-area-at-startup) and added the Applet. But the applet says *"Tomboy Notes" has quit unexpectedly* and a reload doesn't work; the message appears again.
- starting it from terminal gives [this error report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/569058/).
- When I enter `ls` the note file, I get `-rw-r--r-- 1 torben torben 0 2011-02-17 09:09 /home/torben/.local/share/tomboy/f3370271-6210-4b78-8b4a-c31cc2af6935.note`

How can I fix what's wrong?

Comment: Try starting `tomboy` from a terminal (e.g., gnome-terminal, or xterm).   See if any interesting errors pop up.   
Tomboy relies on mono, so if there are failures in mono, you'll have issues with tomboy as well.

Comment: What a great and simple idea! I've added the result above.

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/torben/.local/share/tomboy/f3370271-6210-4b78-8b4a-c31cc2af6935.note` show?

Comment: Looks like it might be blowing up on accessing the directory or the file, so an `ls` is a good place to start .

Comment: Thanks! `ls` result posted in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that note is corrupted, try moving  it:

```
mv /home/torben/.local/share/tomboy/f3370271-6210-4b78-8b4a-c31cc2af6935.note ~/Desktop
```

and then start Tomboy again.

Comment: Yep, that worked! I moved all notes to the desktop and then Tomboy could start. I quit it and moved one note back, then started Tomboy again. Quit, repeat. Only one note is broken - and that's the only one I have!! The other 3 are the built-in samples. **Is there no way to recover that note??** It's my Ubuntu installation diary.... ironic, isn't it!

Comment: I tried to open the note in gedit; it said *Unexpected error: Error opening file: Input/output error* ...

Comment: @torbengb The gedit error is consistent with the note being corrupted, unfortunately. My notes get corrupted fairly often -- probably worth making regular backups.

Comment: Thanks. I stopped using Tomboy after that early crash. I'm now only using (n-)Evernote.